"The JavaScript runtime exited unexpectedly" when making a HTTP POST request
I'm working on a Google Apps Script that interacts with the Canvas Data 2 API and Google Cloud Storage. The script retrieves data from the API, processes it, and uploads it to Google Cloud Storage, eventually loading it into BigQuery.
The problem arises when I set the trigger to run the script hourly. Most of the time, the script fails with the error "The JavaScript runtime exited unexpectedly." This error consistently occurs after the script logs the blob size, the ID of the stored file in Google Drive, and the fetched URL of the Google Cloud Storage. Please refer to the following image:

Here is the relevant part of my script:
// Function to request the URL to download the zip file. 

function requestObjectUrl(object_id) {
  console.log("Starting requestObjectUrl with object_id: " + object_id);

  const accessToken = getAccessToken(); 
  const apiUrl = 'https://api-gateway.instructure.com/dap/object/url';
  const payload = JSON.stringify([{"id": object_id}]);

  const options = {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    payload: payload
  };

  try {
    console.log("Sending POST request to: " + apiUrl);
    console.log("Payload: " + payload);
    console.log("Options: " + JSON.stringify(options, null, 2));

    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, options);
    var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

    if (data.urls && data.urls[object_id] && data.urls[object_id].url) {
      console.log("Received URL: " + data.urls[object_id].url);

      var fileResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(data.urls[object_id].url);
      var blob = fileResponse.getBlob();
      var blobSize = blob.getBytes().length;

      console.log("Blob size: " + blobSize + " bytes.");

      var fileName = "ファイル名.zip";
      var folderId = "1QDBwdHWxfmq7PDRPD7HIfjEVpP6rPra5";
      var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
      var file = folder.createFile(blob.setName(fileName));
      var fileId = file.getId();
      var finalFileName = fileId + ".gz";
      file.setName(finalFileName);

      console.log("File stored in Google Drive with ID: " + fileId);
      return fileId;
    } else {
      console.log("Error: URL not found in response. Full response: " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
      return null;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Error in requestObjectUrl function: " + e.toString());
    console.log("Stack trace: " + e.stack);
    return null;
  }
}

function uploadFileToCloudStorage(fileId, storageBucket, filePath) {
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  const blob = file.getBlob();
  const bytes = blob.getBytes();

  const API = `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b`;
  const location = encodeURIComponent(`${file.getName()}`);
  const url = `${API}/${storageBucket}/o?uploadType=media&name=${location}`;

  
 Logger.log ( `fetch: ${url}` );
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    contentLength: bytes.length,
    contentType: blob.getContentType(),
    payload: bytes,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true 
  });


  const result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
};


function fromStorageToBQ(fileId) {
  var gcsUri = 'gs://canvas_data2/' + fileId + '.gz';
  var bigQueryJobConfig = {
    configuration: {
      load: {
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: BIGQUERY_PROJECT_ID,
          datasetId: BIGQUERY_DATASET_ID,
          tableId: BIGQUERY_TABLE_ID,
        },
        sourceUris: [gcsUri],
        sourceFormat: 'CSV',
        autodetect: false,
        writeDisposition: 'WRITE_APPEND',
        skipLeadingRows: 1
      }
    }
  };

  
  const jobResult = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(bigQueryJobConfig, BIGQUERY_PROJECT_ID);
  Logger.log(jobResult);
}

I have set detailed logging to understand where the script might be failing. The logs show the process reaches the point where the blob is fetched and its size is logged, the file is stored in Google Drive, and the fetched URL of the GCS is logged. However, the script then fails with "The JavaScript runtime exited unexpectedly."
I suspect the issue might be in the requestObjectUrl or fromStorageToBQ functions, but I am unable to pinpoint the exact cause. I also assume the issue may lay in this code snipet, that was taken from the script above.
Logger.log ( `fetch: ${url}` );
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    contentLength: bytes.length,
    contentType: blob.getContentType(),
    payload: bytes,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true 
  });

I expect the script to run hourly without encountering this runtime error. Here are some steps I have already tried:

Adding extensive logging to trace the issue.
Verifying the API calls and responses.
Ensuring the payload and headers are correctly formatted.
Checking for any network or timeout issues.
Changing the trigger from hourly to every 12 hours, 6 hours, 4 hours, etc.
Tested the script with a different data table instead of 'web_logs', however only 'web_logs' fail when I run it the script.

I have also provided an image a screenshot of the 'Executions' page. Function I ran, the type of excecution, the start date, duration of the execution and status (Failed/Completed
As you can see, I don't suspect the duration of execution is a suspect in this issue, as it varies between the 'completed' and 'failed' executions. The blob size for the completed operations are usually less than 30 MB, and commonly below 15 MB. For the failed operations, the blob size is usually between 31 MB~70 MB. But commonly closer to 31 MB.
Please let me know if you need me to provide more details. Any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I ran the debugger, but it doesn't show me which line is the cause of the issue. It only shows me when the error occured. You can refer to the 1st attached screenshot.

Thank you for replying. From your reply, in your question, only the function uploadFileToCloudStorage occurs an error The JavaScript runtime exited unexpectedly. and other functions are not related to the function?

@Tanaike I have other functions and I have a strong assumption that they are not related to the issue.
The total number of functions I have are 8. I will briefly describe what they do and how they are related to each other.

GetAccessToken():
Purpose: Fetches an OAuth2 access token using client credentials and caches it for reuse.
Description: Checks if the access token is available in the cache. If not, it makes a request to the token URL, retrieves the token, caches it for 3599 seconds (just under an hour), and returns the token.


@Tanaike

fetchListOfTables():
Purpose: Fetches a list of tables from the Canvas Data 2 API.
Description: Calls getAccessToken() to get the current access token, then makes a GET request to the Canvas Data 2 API to retrieve the list of tables.


@Tanaike

fetchSchemaOfTable():
Purpose: Fetches the schema of a specific table from the Canvas Data 2 API.
Description: Similar to fetchListOfTables(), it retrieves the access token and then makes a GET request to the API to get the schema of the specified table.


@Tanaike

fetchSnapshot()
Purpose: Fetches a snapshot of data from a specific table.
Description: Retrieves the access token, then makes a POST request to the API to fetch data. It handles the API's asynchronous nature by checking the status of the request and retrying if it's still running or waiting. It returns a list of object IDs from the data.


@Tanaike

requestObjectUrl(object_id):
Purpose: Requests the URL to download a zip file for a given object ID.
Description: Uses the access token to make a POST request to the API to get the download URL for a specific object ID. It then fetches the file as a blob, uploads it to Google Drive, and returns the file ID.


@Tanaike

uploadFileToCloudStorage(fileId, storageBucket, filePath):

Purpose: Uploads a file from Google Drive to Google Cloud Storage.
Description: Fetches the file from Google Drive by its ID, gets its blob, and uploads it to the specified Cloud Storage bucket.

@Tanaike

fromStorageToBQ(fileId):

Purpose: Loads data from Google Cloud Storage into BigQuery.
Description: Constructs a BigQuery job configuration for loading data from a Cloud Storage URI and inserts the job into BigQuery to append the data to a specified table.

Tanaike

runAllFunctions():

Purpose: Executes all the above functions in sequence.
Description: First it calls getAccessToken() to ensure the token is available. Then calls fetchSnapshot() to get a list of object IDs.Then, it iterates over the object IDs, calling requestObjectUrl() to get file IDs and then uploading these files to Cloud Storage and loading them into BigQuery using uploadFileToCloudStorage() and fromStorageToBQ().
Lastly, it updates the lastExecutionTime property to the current date and time.

Thank you for replying. In my experience, when an error The JavaScript runtime exited unexpectedly. occurs, the amount of use of the memory in the process of the script is possibly to be related to the error. So, I thought that first, I am required to know your process. So, I asked like my 1st and 2nd comments. Unfortunately, from your reply and your showing script, I cannot still understand your situation. But, I would like to support you. When I could correctly understand your process and find the issue, I would like to think of a solution.

@Tanaike
What other information can I provide you with?
Would you like me to provide you with the full GAS code?

@MoatazKhan can you add the try/catch in the functions that does not have it and try again? - I was thinking that either a timeout (this happens if it exceeds the 5-minutes threshold) or the blob file is too large or if you don't have more space/memory on Google Drive...

Related: One of two errors: Out of memory or Javascript runtime exited unexpectedly

@MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Yeah, I tried that and it did exceed the 5 minutes threshold. Also the blob size was too large, around 52 MB. So I reduced it and compressed it and made the trigger run on smaller internals.

@MoatazKhan if those changes solved your issue, please, post it as an answer - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer. Thank you.

@MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Yeah, I tried that and it did exceed the 5 minutes threshold. Also the blob size was too large, around 52 MB. So I reduced it and compressed it and made the trigger run on smaller internals.
